# IE7 display wrong ALT-tag when image is wrapped in a link?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, alt

I have a question about IE7 and how it ”interprets” **title** and **alt** HTML tags.
I’ve this constalation on a site:

```
<a title="My Name" alt=" My Name " class="profile_image" href="/members/my-ane">
<img rc="/uploads/sfguarduserprofile/229/11066_60x60_3f9ee652879b2e3209698830c9ff1583.jpeg" alt="11066_60x60_3f9ee652879b2e3209698830c9ff1583">
</a>
```

Now, when hover with my cursor in IE 8+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, you-name-it it shows “My Name” in the alt-box.

But when heading over to IE7, it shows: 11066_60x60_3f9ee652879b2e3209698830c9ff1583 which would be the image alt tag.

I have the possibility to change the alt text on the image but if there is any solution other than that, I would very much appreciate it so I don’t use too much time on a relatively small problem in a single browser.
And are there any explanation why IE7 can’t figure this out oppose to its bigger brothers, IE8, 9+ ??

Sincere
- Mestika

Comment: yeah i would just put the `title` on the img

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the alt attribute should serve as alternative content in case the image doesn't load.  In your case, there is no contextual need for an alt tag, as a user that cannot view the profile image does not *need* to see the image to understand the rest of the content.

The image should have an empty alt attribute [per the WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content-1.html#a-purely-decorative-image-that-doesn%27t-add-any-information).